# Overriding webkit-scrollbar in UI5

Tags: css, sapui5

In console if I see, following classes are present:

```
html.sap-desktop ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

html.sap-desktop ::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

html.sap-desktop ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
```

I wanted to give  blue color to scroll bar and change width. So this is what I did. Please tell if  good idea, if not what other ways can be used.

```
.sapUiBody .sapMPageEnableScrolling::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;

}

.sapUiBody .sapMPageEnableScrolling::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
 }

.sapUiBody .sapMPageEnableScrolling::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {

    background-color: #005daa;
    height: 3px !important;

}

One more issue I am facing is, when I hover over my scrollbar, it becomes grey.
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you share the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below CSS in your style sheet and update your colors

```
.sap-desktop ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 16px !important;
}
.sap-desktop ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #005483 !important;/* Update color */
}
.sap-desktop ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover { /* Scrollbar hover */
    background-color: #d14900 !important; /* Update hover color */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firt of all it is not a good idea to modify css classess directly..this will change all the instance of say scrollbar in your app...give a css class to parent and then modify the css
e.g

```
.parentCssClass .sap-desktop ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 16px !important;
}
```